# Xampp do not open php page

Tags: php, xampp

I've a index page in a PHP format (index.php), but I can't open it with XAMPP.

If I type the path of the page (http://localhost/projectfolder/index.php) it says `object not found`.

But instead if I type the path of a HTML page that is in the same folder it works. The paths are both correct.

I don't know what is the problem, I hope anyone could help me.

Comment: I've already executed the file (setup.bat)

Comment: Can you restart you computer or xampp?

Comment: I've restarted XAMPP and my pc, no changes.

Comment: Make sure you start Apache & Mysql from control panel and they turned to green.. the click on admin for Apache it will redirect you to http://localhost/dashboard/
also can you post the log file xampp-control.log in xampp root

Comment: What do you see, when you just visit http://localhost ?

Comment: if i visit "localhost" it says (object not found)

Comment: I don't understand, if I rename the index file into html it works, instead if it is in php it don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error were in this code line `<?php require "scripts/session.php"; ?>` 
thanks anyone

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have installed xampp in C:\xammp

You need to place you file inside c:\xampp\htdocs\file.php for the file to work

then open it on you browser as

localhost/file.php

Comment: I think you might mean `htdocs` not `htcdocs` wonder what smart phone you use?

Comment: the project folder was in htdocs, i've copied the files directly into htdocs, nothing has yet changed.

Comment: @frankj just type in localhost in the browser

Comment: It says "object not found", i'm freaking out

Comment: is xammp even running give me a screenshot of xammp

Comment: I've tried to restart it many times, it is running even with privileges. http://imgur.com/JauFjxw